# How to load data service done first when app starting in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, service

This is my Angular App. My app will get data from API (temporarily in JSON file) and show in many another sibling component. So I decide to create a **category.service.ts** that I get and store data in. I using APP_INITIALIZER to run this service first when my app started. But there is a problem that: This service is running first, AppComponent runs before service get data done. So my view have empty of data.

If I click button routing to this component, everything run perfect. But when I go to this component by url path or F5(refresh page), nothing is shown

**category.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CategoryService {
  DATA_CATEGORIES = 'assets/categories.json';
  private _categories = [];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  get categories() {
    return this._categories;
  }
  Init(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<void>(resolve => {
      this.http.get(this.DATA_CATEGORIES).subscribe(data => {
        this._categories = Array.from(Object.keys(data), k => data[k]);
        console.log("load data...");

      });
      resolve();
    });
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
export function initializeCategoryService(catService: CategoryService) {
  return (): Promise<any> => {
    return catService.Init();
  }
}
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    StoriesFilterPipe,
    ViewStoryComponent,
    ViewCatComponent,
    FrontEndComponent,
    SearchComponent,
    BackEndComponent,
    CrudStoryFormComponent,
    CrudStoryComponent,
    JwPaginationComponent,
    CrudCatComponent,
    CrudCatFormComponent,
    CrudCatSearchResultComponent,
    CatListComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    StoryService,
    CategoryService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initializeCategoryService, deps: [CategoryService], multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: try to use *ngIf in your app.component.html until your data is loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I will suggest is to use `Observable`

like in your category service

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
export class CategoryService {
    private loadDataSub = new Subject<any>();
    loadDataObservable$ = this.loadDataSub.asObservable();

    emitLoadDataSuccess() {
        this.loadDataSub.next();
    }

Init(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<void>(resolve => {
      this.http.get(this.DATA_CATEGORIES).subscribe(data => {
        this._categories = Array.from(Object.keys(data), k => data[k]);
        console.log("load data...");
        this.emitLoadDataSuccess(); // here we are emitting event
      });
      resolve();
    });
 }
}
```

And In your component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private categoryService: CategoryService) {
          this.categoryService.loadDataObservable$.subscribe(() => {
              // here you can get data, this will only trigger when data is loaded from API
          });
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. But I want to get data and store it to attribute **categories** in Service. I stuck in it ;((

Comment: I didn't get you.... In my answer, I am storing data in category service only, And in component, we are binding an event which will trigger when your api load is complete. At this point, you have confirmation that data is loaded and the you get that data from your service using your `categories` method of service

Comment: you can show loader till data is loaded, and in your subscription you can hide loader as data is loaded

Comment: thank you i got it, what is "updateRowSub" property?

Comment: It's actually `loadDataSub` .... copy pasted code from my working project, though edited code :)

Answer (score 1):

This is common case - i.e. you shows page while data is not avaliable yet - at slow and bad connections for instance, and it can do even more - connection was broken and data was nto recieved.

So, your page should be able to show not only data recieved, but also two another states: loading and error.

(So the advise is "add loader").

Answer (score 0):

```js
// data.service.ts

import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  private _categories = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  get categories() {
    return this._categories;
  }
  getData(): Promise<any[]> {
    return new Promise<any[]>(resolve => {
      this.http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/18qku4').subscribe(data => {
        this._categories = Array.from(Object.keys(data), k => data[k]);
        console.log("load data...");
        resolve(this._categories);
      });
    });
  }
}


// app.module.ts

import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { ListDataComponent } from "./list-data/list-data.component";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { DataService } from "./data.service";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import {DetailComponent} from './detail/detail.component'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: "", component: ListDataComponent },
      { path: "detail", component: DetailComponent }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, ListDataComponent,DetailComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}


//list-data.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { DataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-list-data",
  templateUrl: "./list-data.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./list-data.component.css"],
  providers: [DataService],
})
export class ListDataComponent implements OnInit {
  categories = [];
  constructor(service: DataService) {
    service.getData().then(data => {
      debugger;
      this.categories = data;
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

There are alternatives to resolve this issue:

- One is you can use a loader which you can display until the service call finishes.
- Second is you can use *ngIf="categories?.length" which will keep your component hides until your service call finishes.

I hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: i tried your second way. If I click button routing to this component, everything run perfect. But when I go to this component by path or F5, nothing is shown

Comment: Can you please tell what issue you face when you refresh using F5. What is your expectation when you press F5?

It would be good if you can create a stackblitz for this.

Comment: What do you mean by nothing is shown ? Are you getting any console error ?

Comment: this is my app: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-webstr
there is no console error. When I run or refresh, nothing is shown. When I click button to go to other component and go back, at that time my data is appeared

Comment: You are right, service ajax call is finishing after the component loads. So again 2 ways:
- One is We can notify component that data has been loaded and i will not prefer this.
- Second is We can change the structure of our project

I am updating my answer with changes i am doing in files.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: why 3 files are the same. I think there is a mistake

Comment: i have voted. Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.